# Hide Navigation Bar in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I am trying to hide the navigation bar in a WPF project using;

```
 <Frame x:Name="_MainFrame" ContentRendered="_MainFrame_ContentRendered" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden">
```

The content is loaded/changes when button_click are triggered by user (code behind below);

```
_MainFrame.Navigate(new Pages.Projects.Views.Create());
```

is have also used;

```
_MainFrame.NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;

_MainFrame.NavigationUIVisibility = System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;
```

but still the navigation bar show up with default styling. Is there any other way of hiding the bar?

Comment: Where do you set NavigationUIVisibility? In the Constructor of the Window? For me in a sample project everything works fine. Maybe you can post some more code of your Code Behind (.xaml.cs).

Comment: Inside MainWindow  after Initialized() also in button_click {}...